# How to set Sentry log level in runtime in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, sentry

I'm using Sentry with .NET Core which is currently configured as

```
"SentryOptions": {
  "Dsn": "https://...",
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "UseRequestFactory": false,
  "IsDisabled": false
},
```

which is loaded in `ConfigureServices`

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISentryProvider, SentryProvider>();
serviceCollection.AddOptions().Configure<SentryOptions>(section);
```

Is there a way to change `LogLevel` in runtime? I don't want to have to change the appsettings.json and re-deploy just to toggle a config.

Comment: It depends on internal sentry code, I think, but there is an option configurable option [`reloadOnChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-3.1#monitor-for-configuration-changes) for `AddJsonFile` method. You can try to play with it.

Comment: Are you referring to Sentry.Extensions.Logging or other package? What LogLevel do you mean? The Sentry.AspNetCore package already loads the Sentry configuration section so you shouldn't need to load it yourselve

Comment: @BrunoGarcia we're using `SharpRaven`. By LogLevel I mean that it is configured to `Error` but I want to be able to change to something else in runtime.

Comment: I'm asking if you're talking about the level of which Sentry will capture things as events or add as breadcrumbs? Or some other level? Sentry has integration with logging libraries but it's not a logging tool per-se. Have you taken a look at the samples? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0):

Is this a ASP.NET Core app or just .NET Core using generic Host? Are you using the `Sentry.AspNetCore` integration? That integration does load the `Sentry` key from `appsettings.json` automatically so you don't need to touch the DI container for any Sentry configuration. It [has docs here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/aspnetcore/).

`Sentry.AspNetCore` depends on `Sentry.Extension.Logging` ([docs here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/microsoft-extensions-logging/)) so it brings the support to capturing all `LogError`s and higher as errors and `LogInformation` and lower as breadcrumbs (default settings). That means you can use DI to take `IHub` or `ISentryClient` anywhere in your app.

Your answer is likely: The specific settings [`MinimumBreadcrumbLevel`](https://getsentry.github.io/sentry-dotnet/api/Sentry.Extensions.Logging.SentryLoggingOptions.html#Sentry_Extensions_Logging_SentryLoggingOptions_MinimumBreadcrumbLevel) and [`MinimumEventLevel`](https://getsentry.github.io/sentry-dotnet/api/Sentry.Extensions.Logging.SentryLoggingOptions.html#Sentry_Extensions_Logging_SentryLoggingOptions_MinimumEventLevel) are not reloaded if you change their value in the `appsettings.json`. For example, you could disable Sentry altogether:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Sentry": "None", // Disables Sentry
    }
}
```

More details on the [ASP.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/).

Since this is an integration built on top of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package, you can configure the general app's log level and it should affect Sentry's loggers. They don't have auto reload of configuration at a higher level. It's the job of each logging provider to reload the configuration.

A way around this if you'd like to try (undocumented/unsupported): You could resole the `IOptions<SentryOptions>` from the container (don't register it yourself, the SDK already does that) and change the LogLevels at runtime. The logger instance holds a reference to the options and checks the level at runtime:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/f5f57545a1f17820d8beda3238ad76fc7ceac7ef/src/Sentry.Extensions.Logging/SentryLogger.cs#L40-L41

Finally, note that if you use Serilog, it changes the logging backend a things are different in that case. Sentry offers a [Sentry.Serilog package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Serilog/) too.